# Bounding the Norm of a Powered Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Using the definition of the induced norm, I was wondering if the following inequality is true?

$$\|A^{n+m}\| \leq \|A^{n}\|\|A^{m}\|$$

Answer (score 1):

Any induced operator norm is a sub-multiplicative matrix norm: $|| AB || \leq ||A|| \ ||B||$ (results from $||ABx|| \leq || A || || Bx || \leq || A || ||B || ||x ||$ and $||AB || = \sup_{||x = 1 ||} || ABx||$). Then $|| A^{n+m}|| = || A^n A^m|| \leq || A^n || \ || A^m||$.